# Selenium not getting cookies

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to save the cookies with using an explicit profile. The code is as follows:

```
browser_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
browser_profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)
browser_profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=browser_profile)
driver.get("https://google.com")
result = driver.get_cookies()
# result= []
```

If I simplify the code (or I use the predetermined profile), I will get a result:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com")
result = driver.get_cookies()
# result= [{'name': 'CONSENT', 'value': 'WP.272dd2', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.google.com', 'expiry': 2145916800, 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False}, {'name': 'NID', 'value': '144=DdGwYa-bPLiDsp-IPfZdRdkjsQXMzLeex53S9nmb3uzp687exfmO_Z8Hq2bDgEQu58Kq16MX7wI0UhHx6S1y_vJU9z8GYylKy4kBEmQE8e6EJnupEClBy_ZbEPFsBklbsPzkG-tS3RfqzIy-COjamlZHiQJFp0YLlegUWMlzq1k', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.google.com', 'expiry': 1556392000, 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': True}, {'name': '1P_JAR', 'value': '2018-10-26-19', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.google.com', 'expiry': 1543172801, 'secure': False, 'httpOnly': False}]
```

However, in this way I cannot set the exact parameters that I want. I would like to know why and how to solve this problem. Ideas? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due this preference setting. when I run with false condition, it is returning cookies.

```
browser_profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)
```

Looks like privatebrowsing blocks the cookies tracking throw webdriver. But when i try to get through javascript exector with private browsing , I get the cookies.

```
print(driver.execute_script("return document.cookie"))
```

Comment: You're completely right, and it's a weird behavior though. The second part of the answer I know that works, but I aim to pass cookies via selenium, and the javascript response is completely different and doesn't take into account `HttpOnly` as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  I was using a profile that had privatebrowsing enabled on disk (not in my C# code), so I didn't even know to look for this being the cause.